# personal messaging service design a side service for a competition website where users can come ice for competition contestants?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, message, messaging, joomla2.5

i need to develop a personal messaging service for contestants of a racing competition . I need a cms(preferably free) which can do this.

The requirements are pretty basic .

1)when teams log in g\they can see inbox where they can see messages sent from administrators.
and reply to them or send new ones to administrators

2)they cant send messages to other teams.

3)attachments can also be sent in messages

4)when administrator is sending messages it can be sent to one ,or more or all of the teams(according to administrators wish)

5)more than one administrator accounts can also be created

6)Looks dont matter as this will just be a back end

P.S. if possible in joomla how can this be achieved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should test messaging components (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/communication/pms) and define user groups with associated rights.